# javax.servlet.ServletException: File &quot;/WEB-INF/include/httpbase.jsp&quot; not found

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

I am just working on web services using Axis 2 implementaion.

Steps:

a.  Download axis 2 ja from web site

b.  Add jar to eclipse using windows --- preferences --- webservices --- axis 2 preferences

c.  Create dynamic web project with name Axis2CalService

d.  Create class with name CalService and project dir com.xyz.service

e.  Then right click on CalService class ---- new ----- others ------ web services ----- webservice it will perform some things in background

```
     i. Axis 2 jar in lib folder
     ii.    WSDL file created
    iii.    Same procedure as of AXIS 1
```

g.  brosing to http://localhost:8080/Axis2Service getting error

Using Axis 2 -1.7.3 and tomacat 7 server

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this? I'm having the same issue, when using `ant create.war` from `axis2/webapp` directory and then deploying `dist/axis2.war` to Tomcat.

Comment: while creating java application select servelt 2.5 which resolved my issue

Answer (score 2):

Good news.

I have downloaded [axis2-1.6.2-bin.zip](https://archive.apache.org/dist/axis/axis2/java/core/1.6.2/) and added it in eclipse using Window -> Preferences -> Web Services -> Axis2 Preferences ->Axis2 Runtime

Then created webservice from java class.

Using axis2-1.6.2-bin instead of axis2-1.7.3-bin resolved the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. I had the same issue and reverted back to axis2-1.6.2 and it my web service now works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have downloaded axis2 binay distribution.

You have to download axis2 WAR distribution axis2-1.7.3-war.zip from [https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.html] and attach in your project. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by using an older verison of axis2 jars. Use the axis2-1.6.2 jars instead of "axis2-1.7.3". Add the jars in axis2 preferneces and create new project and deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

copy include folder to WEB-INF like this:

[image: picture]

Answer (score -1):

1.Go to the Axis2 folder and copy file: xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar to the \lib folder.

2.Past it into your tomcat folder and then restart the tomcat server

Ex: \apache-tomcat-7.0.67\lib and past it

[image: Img]

Comment: This does not correct the problem at all. And there's no need for this, if the web app already has access to those classes.